# Add credit card to apple wallet from react website

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, apple-wallet

We are trying to add card issued from brex to apple wallet on our react website. There is already an option available to do the same https://github.com/erikpoort/react-native-wallet but it is in native and our site runs on react js.

Is it possible to do same from our react website as well? If it is possible how so?

Comment: Only native apps with a special entitlement from Apple can add payment cards to the apple wallet. The app is typically provided by the card issuer.

Comment: Could you find a solution?